# Read 16bit channel PSD file by library psd.js return empty

Tags: javascript, psd

I am using library **psd.js** [lib here](https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js) to read data from PSD file. When my file PSD is 8 bit channel. But when I change my file PSD to channel 16 bit, parse data return empty.

My question is how to read 16 bit channel PSD file or are there other JS library to read 16 bit channel PSD file ?

My code:

> var PSD = require('psd');
>
> const filePSDPath = 'psd file.psd';
>
> var psd = PSD.fromFile(filePSDPath);
>
> psd.parse();
>
> console.log("psd: ", psd.tree());

Comment: you can check this issue https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js/issues/168